# Ubuntu IP Redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ip-address, url

This is my problem. I have a Ubuntu computer running Apache/SQL/phpMyAdmin the goal that I want is that when someone logs on to the network if they type in *encc* in the url bar it will direct them to this computer. The server's IP address is: 192.168.0.52 . How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To make a bare name `encc` work will require several things.

- First you will need a search domain setup on DNS settings of all your clients.  You would use whatever your domain is, but for this question I'll assume `example.org`.
- Next you need to setup a DNS record `encc.example.org.` within your domain that with the IP of your server.
- Finally setup a virtual host for `encc.example.org.`, and also setup an ServerAlias alias so that virtual host will handle the bare name `encc` as well.

Comment: And/or make sure the client machines you want sent to the short name have the appropriate dns suffix in their search list.